# haproxy domain redirect not working

Tags: haproxy

`https://www.foo.bar` is my main domain.

I want to redirect as well everything to `bar.foo`.

It works fine with `http` requests, but if I try `https://bar.foo`, I get a certificate error and the redirect to `https://www.foo.bar` does not occur.

The relevant part from config should be:

```
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443

    redirect prefix https://www.foo.bar code 301 if { hdr(host) -i foo.bar}

    redirect prefix https://www.foo.bar code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.bar.foo }
    redirect prefix https://www.foo.bar code 301 if { hdr(host) -i bar.foo }

    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
```

Where is my mistake?  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect requests unless you have a valid certificate for the domain that is *originally* requested by the browser.

TLS must be successfully negotiated *before* the redirect can happen.  That is a standard constraint in https, not specific to HAProxy.  You need certificates that are valid for all domains for which you are serving any kind of requests, even redirects.